# How do I change a value in an XML file for certain nodes (which are referenced in another XML file)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a large XML file and I need to set certain values in it to '2' where the ID number of a parent node matches one in another XML file.

My large XML file 'file1.xml' is in the following format:

```
    <institution>
    <ukprn>1234</ukprn>
    <course>
        <courseID>1</courseID>
        <courseaim>X99</courseaim>
    </course>
    <student>
        <birthdate>30/10/1985</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST>
            <FC>1</FC>
            <elq>4</elq>
        </instance>
    </student>
    <student>
        <birthdate>01/02/1999</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
            <FC>2</FC>
            <elq>2</elq>
        </instance>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|2</OWNINST>
            <FC>6</FC>
            <elq>1</elq>
        </instance>
    </student>
</institution>
```

There are multiple students each of which can have multiple instances.

I have another xml file 'File2.xml' which is structured like this:

```
<studentstoadd>
<OWNINST>555466|2</OWNINST>
<OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
</studentstoadd>
```

For each of the students in File2.xml, I would like to change the value of their 'FC' node in File1.xml to '2' no matter what it was previously.  Any students not listed in File2.xml should not be changed.

Please could someone help with this as I don't seem to be able to do it.

This is what I had come up with but it doesn't work, it just inserts the nodes from File2.xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="OWNINST">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2.xml')//Instance[OWNINST=current()/../OWNINST]"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="student/instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoadd/OWNINST]/FC">
    <FC>2</FC>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Mark, if I then had another node to match on within OWNINST, how would I do modify the above code to do that? So if there were multiple <MODID> nodes within <instance> and I wanted to change a value of a <MODOUT> within <MODID> then I'd need to match on OWNINST and then on MODID: <Instance><OWNINST>123456|1</OWNINST><studentonmodule><MODID>08|29400></MODID><MODOUT>01</MODOUT></studentonmodule><studentonmodule><MODID>08|29091></MODID><MODOUT>04</MODOUT></studentonmodule></Instance>

Comment: *Martin (not Mark!!)

Comment: Please ask a new question with properly formatted code snippets.

Comment: Sorry, yes that would make more sense, I have now done that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952701/change-values-in-xml-based-to-those-referenced-in-another-xml-file-based-on-mult#)  Thanks very much Martin, appreciate your time.